# Otto-Beau cycle : where does the big formula for efficiency come from?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-engine

In one exercice, I have to compute the efficiency of an Otto-Beau cycle.

[image: Otto-Beau cycle]

We saw that $\eta = \frac{"win"}{"spent"} = \frac{W_{cycle}}{Q_+} = \frac{W_{a->b} + W_{c->d}}{Q_+}$

Knowing that :

- $a = \frac{V_a}{V_b} = 9$
- $T_a = 300K$
- $T_c = 2400K$
- $P_a = 1 atm$
- $\gamma = 1.5$

Performing some calculations :

- $W_{a->b} = \frac{P_aV_a}{\gamma-1}(a^{\gamma-1}-1)$
- $W_{c->d} = \frac{nRT_c}{\gamma-1}({\frac{1}{a^{\gamma-1}}}-1)$

However, in the correction we get something else :

$\eta = \frac{Q_+ \cdot \frac{(a^{\gamma - 1})}{(\frac{T_c}{T_a})-a^{\gamma-1}} + Q_+ \cdot (\frac{T_c)}{(T_c-T_a \cdot a^{\gamma-1})}}{Q_+}$

How can we get that formula ?

Comment: In terms of Ta and a, what is the temperature at point B?  In terms of Tc and a, what is the temperature at point D?

Comment: $T_b = T_a \cdot a^{\gamma - 1} = 900K$ and $T_d = \frac{T_c}{a^{\gamma - 1}}$

Comment: So, in terms of Cv, Ta, Tc, and a, how much heat is added from B to C, and how much heat is removed from D to A?

Comment: $Q_{c->b} = \int_{T_b}^{T_c} nc_vdT = nc_v(T_c - T_b) = \frac{nR}{\gamma-1}(T_c - Ta \cdot a^{\gamma-1}) = Q_+$ 

$Q_{d->a} = \int_{T_d}^{T_a} nc_vdT = nc_v(T_a - T_d) = \frac{nR}{\gamma-1}(T_a - \frac{Tc}{a^{\gamma-1}}) = Q_-$

Comment: Both these results are correct.  You know that, for the cycle, $\Delta U=0$.  So this means the $W_{net}=Q_{net}$.  Do you know how to determine the efficiency from this?  If so, let's see what you get.

Comment: I get that : $\eta = \frac{|-Q_{cycle}|}{Q_+} = \frac{Q_+ + Q_-}{Q_+} = 1 + \frac{Q_-}{Q_+} = 1 + \frac{\frac{nR}{\gamma-1}(T_a - \frac{Tc}{a^{\gamma-1}})}{\frac{nR}{\gamma-1}(T_c - Ta \cdot a^{\gamma-1})} = 1 + \frac{(T_a - \frac{Tc}{a^{\gamma-1}})}{(T_c - Ta \cdot a^{\gamma-1})}$

Comment: That can be simplified by multiplying numerator and denominator of the right hand term by $a^{\gamma-1}$

Comment: I get $1 - \frac{1}{a^{\gamma-1}}$

Comment: Interesting result.